# How to style textbox control based on the span (next to the texbox) with error class

Tags: css

When the email is invalid the span will be visible with the error message "Invalid Email". In addition to that I also need the textbox to be having a red border. How to add border color to the textbox when the immediate span has style visibility as visible. Initially on the form load the span style="visibility:hidden;"

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="txtEmail" id="lblEmail" class="form-label">Email</label>
  <input name="txtEmail" value="test@" id="txtEmail" class="email-address form-control" type="text">
  <span id="spanErrorEmail" class="Email error" style="visibility: visible;">Invalid email</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript. There is no simple answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 itself has email validation and there is no need to use extra coding as for that. You can only use `required` option for input.

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Some people prefer styling their own error messages and having their own messages... so yes there is a need

Comment: Due to certain limitations I would like to use the custom validator. And I'm looking for css to highlight the textbox which is prev to the span element.